# Retrieve php variable in a string of a select <option>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to retrieve one php variable in `jQuery(The $foods['price'])`,but there is another variable and parenthesis on the left and the right of the variable.I tried to place the the php variable between the parenthesis `text()` in the jquery file but not success. How can I retrieve only the `variable($foods['price']` ? I placed the screenshot below

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Questions asking *"Why isn't this code working?"* must include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself.** Please edit your question to follow this guideline and read *["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)* for more information.

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question instead of linking to (or even embedding) images.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not acceptable to have a span inside the option tag, it's not valid html.

Looking at your code you should apply a data attribute or a value to your options instead.

For example,

```
<p></p>
<select id="eat" class="form-control">
<?php foreach($foods as $key => $food) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$food['price'];?>"><?=$food['name'];?> - <?=$food['price'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<script>
$("p").text($('#eat').val());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Here doc code to do that loop...

```
$optionsHtml = '<select';
//foreach loop...(add real loop syntax here)
$optionsHTML .= <<<HTML
<option value="{$var['blah']}">{$var['blah2']}</option>
HTML;
//end foreach loop (add real loop syntax here)
$optionsHtml .= '</select>';
```

HTML Section:

```
<section><?=$optionsHtml;?></section
OR
<section><?php echo $optionsHtml; ?></section>
```

Or what is just above...but this way you can put variables in there more readily and fluidly.

Comment: Why do you think the way they're currently outputting the variables isn't working?

Comment: Possibly the space, maybe a php.ini variable... not sure i always use either heredoc or <?=$blah;?>. That being said i think some frameworks i have used don't let the <?=$blah;?> go through cause of some templating conflicts.